# Can't see my site's flash map in an Iframe

Tags: html, flash, iframe

I have a website, which includes a flash map ( http://www.megalim.co.il/ ). 
I try to place an iframe tag in another site(another domain), with my site as a source, it goes well except for the flash map ( I see a white box instead ). 
You can see it: http://www.netravel.co.il/Megalim/

I have to note that I get the following error:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.netravel.co.il/Megalim/ from frame with URL http://www.megalim.co.il/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://www.megalim.co.il.

Hope you can help me, thanks from advance,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, seems like it was an issue of cross-browsers' scripting...